# Android java: How correct send sorted data to listView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I sorted data in format Map<Integer, FindedUser> where Integer is Timestamp in System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 and FindedUser class

```js
Map<Integer, FindedUser> reverseSortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        reverseSortedMap.putAll(addedUsersMap);
    
for (Map.Entry<Integer, FindedUser> entry : reverseSortedMap.entrySet()) {
            FindedUser user = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
            helperMap.put(entry.getKey(), new FindedUser(user.getId(), user.getName(), user.getTimestamp()));
        }
```

and got correct data

```js
1609093171 FindedUser{name='ccc', id='11', timestamp='1609093171'}
1609092871 FindedUser{name='bbb', id='10', timestamp='1609092871'}
1609092015 FindedUser{name='aaa', id='9', timestamp='1609092015'}
```

but when i send it to listView:

```js
MyAdapterHash addedUsersAdapter = new MyAdapterHash(helperMap);
        addedUsersListView.setAdapter(addedUsersAdapter);
        addedUsersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

result is not sorted correct:

```js
1609092015 FindedUser{name='aaa', id='9', timestamp='1609092015'}
1609093171 FindedUser{name='ccc', id='11', timestamp='1609093171'}
1609092871 FindedUser{name='bbb', id='10', timestamp='1609092871'}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: A map is an unordered collection. How is your `MyAdapterHash` implemented?

Comment: I dont see where i can edit my post and dont know NyAdaptedHash is implemented correctly but a problem was with type of map. @Live and Let Live give me LinkedHashMap type. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `helperMap` is of type [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which does not maintain the insertion order.

Change the type of `helperMap` to [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which gives you a predictable iteration order.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.